# PHP client socket connection with C# Socket Server

Tags: php

I am trying to connect to my C# server from my website using PHP.

I would like to keep the connection alive through all pages.

C# Server: Port 100

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace Multi_Server
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Socket _serverSocket;
        private static readonly List<Socket> _clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
        private const int _BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
        private const int _PORT = 100;
        private static readonly byte[] _buffer = new byte[_BUFFER_SIZE];

        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Title = "Server";
            SetupServer();
            Console.ReadLine(); // When we press enter close everything
            CloseAllSockets();
        }

        private static void SetupServer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting up server...");
            _serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _PORT));
            _serverSocket.Listen(5);
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
            Console.WriteLine("Server setup complete");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Close all connected client (we do not need to shutdown the server socket as its connections
        /// are already closed with the clients)
        /// </summary>
        private static void CloseAllSockets()
        {
            foreach (Socket socket in _clientSockets)
            {
                socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                socket.Close();
            }

            _serverSocket.Close();
        }

        private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket;

            try
            {
                socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException) // I cannot seem to avoid this (on exit when properly closing sockets)
            {
                return;
            }

           _clientSockets.Add(socket);
           socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, socket);
           Console.WriteLine("Client connected, waiting for request...");
           _serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
        }

        private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket current = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            int received;

            try
            {
                received = current.EndReceive(AR);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client forcefully disconnected");
                current.Close(); // Dont shutdown because the socket may be disposed and its disconnected anyway
                _clientSockets.Remove(current);
                return;
            }

            byte[] recBuf = new byte[received];
            Array.Copy(_buffer, recBuf, received);
            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recBuf);
            Console.WriteLine("Received Text: " + text);

            if (text.ToLower() == "get time") // Client requested time
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Text is a get time request");
                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
                current.Send(data);
                Console.WriteLine("Time sent to client");
            }
            else if (text.ToLower() == "exit") // Client wants to exit gracefully
            {
                // Always Shutdown before closing
                current.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                current.Close();
                _clientSockets.Remove(current);
                Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Text is an invalid request");
                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Invalid request");
                current.Send(data);
                Console.WriteLine("Warning Sent");
            }

            current.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php

Please do not suggest alternatives (this is a fallback option for non compatible HTML5 browsers)

PHP:

```
<?PHP
 $service_port = 100;
  $address = '10.10.10.12';

  $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
  socket_set_nonblock($socket);

socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);

?>
```

My php code is causing an error on my server when connected.
https://www.anony.ws/i/2015/06/02/Capture1aa49.png

I am having the same issue when trying to connect via python..

```
#!/Python34/python
import socket
HOST = '10.10.10.12'    # The remote host
PORT = 100             # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.sendall('Hello, world')
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print('Received', repr(data))
```

I was able to track down the error... Still not to sure what is causing it..
Message : A TCPIP socket error has occurred (10053): An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
Reason : The server closed the client connection.
Action : Contact the network administrator or server administrator.

The error is happening won the Begin Receive for the server, which is causing the server to close the connection. I believe i am sending information to the server incorrectly, if i take out the receive for the server the connection is not terminated.

Comment: Can you add some error handling on PHP side? [This page explains how](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-connect.php) - and then post the errors so we can see why PHP complains.

Comment: I would like to keep the connection alive through all pages. ... Not possible. The stack trace shows that the data being sent by PHP is not ASCII formatted... its most likely UTF8. In which case you need to use a different decoder to parse the response.

Comment: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately. @N.B.

Comment: I'm getting to the point where i might say screw it and make an executable that takes params to send a message to the server.

Comment: To be clear the connection is making it to the server or else the server wouldnt be crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keeping a connection open with PHP is not good practice and will cause the page to not finish loading. PHP should be closed by the time the web browser receives its output. consider using Javascript not PHP. The reason you connection closes is the handshake.